# Redirect from asp to php not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all asp files to php files. At this point it doesn't matter if the parameters are lost. I tried the code below to accomplish this. But it seems to be ignored. If the asp page is `default.asp`, the url is rewritten to `default.php`, which doesn't exist.

I'm wondering if there is something on the server that is overriding my command or if the command is wrong?

```
RewriteRule ^.asp$ /index.php [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using anchors on both the ends of your URL match pattern. The `^` marks the beginning and `$` marks the end. Since you only want to match URLs ending with `.asp`, use just `$`:

```
RewriteRule \.asp$ /index.php [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule you're looking for is:

```
# Does the file exist?
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
# If so, rewrite the request
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.asp$ /$1.php [R=301,QSA]
```

The ^/? on there is because it's not clear from context whether you're doing this in your main config, or in a .htaccess file. I presume .htaccess since you've used that tag, but, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions but neither worked. When I visit the site from a link that has default.asp in it, the page fails to load and shows: The requested URL /default.php was not found on this server. I tried both suggestions one at a time.